# verilog testbench compare cause errors

Tags: verilog

I have the most peculiar problem that none of the guys in my office came across or know how to handle, maybe you guys will find where's the catch.

In my verilog testbench, I have the following compare code:

```
if (refFifo[7:0] != DUT.fifo[7:0] && rnd == 1) begin
  $display("Error! ref Fifo %h not equal DUT fifo %h after 1 byte", refFifo[7:0], DUT.fifo[7:0]);
  $stop;
end
else if (refFifo[15:0] != DUT.fifo[15:0] && rnd == 2) begin
  $display("Error! ref Fifo %h not equal DUT fifo %h after 2 byte", refFifo[15:0], DUT.fifo[15:0]);
  $stop;
end
```

... (until 5 bytes)
`else

$display("Success!");`
Now, the problem is that the comparison of 2 is *always* failing, while the rest of the comparisons pass smoothly (and this screws up with my runs):
'>Error: ref Fifo 090c not equal DUT fifo 090c after 2 byte'
I tried changing the position of the compare in the process, printing the values before the compare (in case they changed somehow during the compare), adding parenthesis, changing the compare range to [7:0] and building a new environment but nothing helped or gave some indication of what goes wrong with the compare of 2 bytes.
Did anyone ever came across such a problem? does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?
I run with ModelSim 10.1d_1 with no optimization, in case it has something to do with my enigma.
**update** also tried it on ModelSim 10.0d_1, but with no help.

Comment: I added a chat room to discuss the problem: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/38971/verilog-fenomena?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. The result of the `&&` must be `1'b1` for the `$display` to be executed. This means both comparisons must also have a result of `1'b1`, so there aren't any unknowns in `resFifo`, `DUT.fifo`, or `rnd`. You should change your comparison operators to `!==` and `===` to confirm this. ModelSim is also not printing any X's with the `%h` modifier. I'd change this to `%b` just to be sure.

Unless I've missed something obvious, I'd remove the cross-module reference (`DUT.fifo`) and try again. Get a fifo port out of the DUT, and do the comparison against the port value. This might help to track down the issue.

Comment: tried with !== and %b but with no use. since all other comparisons use the same mechanism (resFifo compare to DUT.fifo), I don't see how this could be the problem, but when I use them on waves i can see they are the same. this is a tricky one, isn't it?

Comment: I'd try the `DUT.fifo` thing - remove the cross-module reference, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Wow, that's strange...  What if you add parenthesis like this: ((refFifo[15:0] != DUT.fifo[15:0]) && rnd == 2) to ensure that the operations are done in the correct order?  Just a shot in the dark here... Another thing I would check is to see that another piece of your code is interfering with this IF statement.  Try taking this process out of this file and running it in its own file by itself.

Comment: @Russell I've already tried the parenthesis thing you suggested with no use. the comparison process works at the end of a long process, please elaborate on what you mean by taking it out of the file.

Comment: Something else to try. This is unlikely to be a race problem, because ModelSim will almost certainly only run the scheduler when it reaches an event control in your code, and there are no event controls here. However, it's possible that it also runs the scheduler when it reaches the `$display`, and another process is changing `resFifo` or `DUT.fifo` before the display produce output. Test this by storing their values before `$display` and printing the stored values.

Comment: @EML I tried something similar: printed the values before the compares and seen they are the same as printed after the compare. i didn't try your previous suggestion (taking the fifo out) because i already have a netlist that passed formality.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand my suggestion: don't print the values, but store them instead, and then print the stored values. If there's a race condition in your code, then it is possible (maybe) that the `$display` is showing the variable values *after* the race has taken effect. Print the *stored* values to find out if this is the case. On Formality - the point of my suggestion was to find out if there is a bug in ModelSim related to cross-module references, which is the only complex thing in your code (apart from potential races). The Formality test isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.  You may be hitting a simulator bug; if you can reproduce this in a test case you should submit it to Mentor support.

Here are are some other things to try:

- Create a 5-byte local variable for the DUT value before the `if` statements, and use that in the checks.
- Change the order of the checks so that you look at `rnd` first.  This way the expression will short-circuit and avoid comparing the DUT values for cases which you don't need to check for.
- Refactor the check to use a `case` statement on `rnd`.  Including a default case may help debug any problem where `rnd != 2`.
- Delete the line and re-type it manually.  Or copy/paste another line and change the numbers. I have seen weird cases where a hidden/bad/unicode character will compile and run but cause something to misbehave.